# How do I make a Discord bot using discord.py rewrite that can make bot users that are not real

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have seen a few bots that have made a bot user

one bot called [BetterCensoring](https://top.gg/bot/678993339873493022) did that

[It looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmYnK.png)

does anyone know how to make that?

I have tried to search for an answer a lot but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], including any current implementation you might have, and anything you've tried already to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut With all due respect, this user is asking how to do something they have no idea how to do. As this is achieved with webhooks, if one does not know about webhooks, there is no way to create a minimal reproducible example. This is a question on *how* to do something, but it is concise enough to receive an answer, as it is talking about a very specific phenomena and describes said phenomena with the example bot and image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuff like this is not achieved by actually creating a new user account but rather using a [webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook). The [send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.send) method has the ability to customize **username** and **profile picture** of the message.

Webhooks are most easily created with [`await channel.create_webhook()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_webhook)

Note that a guild can only have 10 webhooks at a time, which is why most bots that use this functionality create a webhook, send a message with it and then delete it right afterwards.

Example (recreating your creeper censoring):

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('bad word'):
        webhook = await message.channel.create_webhook()
        await webhook.send('####', username='Creeper', avatar_url='this is an url leading to the creeper image')
        await webhook.delete()
```